# Hosting a Single Domain on Two Servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting

I have a site example.com which is hosted on a VPS server. The site often deals with downloads, so I can't really server the downloads from the VPS server. So I want to use a dedicated server to store and serve the  downloads from the same Domain itself.

I know I can use a subdomain to achieve this, but I want to use the main domain itself to serve the downloads, like: http://www.example.com/download.zip and not dl.example.com/download.zip .. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an A record on your DNS pointing on your server which you want to deal with downloads.

On your Web Server make a redirection whenever this url is requested:
http://www.example.com/dl/ to point on http://dl.example.com/ by mod_rewrite on apache for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to change the download address on the fly.